# How to insert pictures into Excel files from entering the serial number in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert pictures into Excel files from entering the serial number in a cell.

I get a syntax error where it is trying to insert the pictures. Specifically where it says `.Shapes.AddPicture`.

```vb
Sub picture_insert()
Dim picBild As Picture
Dim blnAvailable As Boolean
Dim link As String
Dim Pattern As String
Dim Serial As String
Dim t As String
Dim P1 As String
Dim P2 As String
link = "\\chimera\home\hillerbr\My Documents\Index project\"
Pattern = Range("A14")
Serial = Range("B14")
t = ".jpg"
P1 = Range("C14")
P2 = Range("D14")
With Worksheets("Data Breakdown")
   
    For Each picBild In .Pictures
        If picBild.Name = "280.1" Then
            'The picture already exists
            blnVorhanden = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next picBild
    'only execute if picture does not yet exist
    If blnVorhanden = False Then
        With .Shapes.AddPicture Filename := link & Pattern & Serial & P1 & t
            .Name = Range("C14")
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 450
            .Height = 500
            .Left = Worksheets("Data Breakdown").Range("A10").Left
            .Top = Worksheets("Data Breakdown").Range("G20").Top
        End With
       With .Shapes.AddPicture Filename := link & Pattern & Serial & P1 & t
            .Name = Range("D14")
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 450
            .Height = 500
            .Left = Worksheets("Data Breakdown").Range("E10").Left
            .Top = Worksheets("Data Breakdown").Range("G20").Top
        End With
    End If
    
End With
   End Sub

Sub Image_Remove()
Dim picBild As Picture
With Worksheets("Data Breakdown")
    
    For Each picBild In .Pictures
        If picBild.Name = Range("C14") Then
            picBild.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next picBild
     For Each picBild In .Pictures
        If picBild.Name = Range("D14") Then
            picBild.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next picBild
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing your variables point to a valid image I found the below code works.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Data Breakdown")
    
    With sht
        With .Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=link & Pattern & Serial & P1 & t, _
                                LinkToFile:=True, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
                                Left:=.Range("A10").Left, Top:=.Range("G20").Top, Width:=450, Height:=500)
                                  
            .Name = "ABC"
            .LockAspectRatio = True
        
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The Help page for [AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture) says there's 7 required parameters.